# Asp.net memory usage - know which part is application and which part is memory cache

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, memory

I have an Asp.Net application, where by time the memory usage is growing up to 2.5GB and more.  Website is using heavily the `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`.

Is there anyway by code to know how much of that memory is used by the `System.Runtime.Caching.MemoryCache`, so I can know if the issue is too much caching, or whether there are memory leaks in the application?

Answer (score 0):

First look at the [PhysicalMemoryLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.physicalmemorylimit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) . How big is it? Set it to a reasonable limit for your environment.

"The PhysicalMemoryLimit property returns the percentage of total physical computer memory that can be used by a single instance of the MemoryCache class. If the cache instance exceeds the specified limit, cache entries are removed."

Also look into [CacheMemoryLimit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.cachememorylimit%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) 
"Gets the amount of memory on the computer, in bytes, that can be used by the cache."

Also beware how many Cache instances your application is using, hopefully it uses [Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.memorycache.default%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Also look into the exprirations of cache entries, in general it's [DefaultCacheCapabilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.caching.defaultcachecapabilities%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)...